# Netlogo - Dynamically change the running time per experiment using Behavior Space

Tags: netlogo

I am running a model multiple times from behavior space. Each time the running length of time needs to be different according to the data imported from the external data source (e.g. the ending time of the last shift of production during a typical day). How to do this in behavior space?

Comment: How to do this may depend on the structure of your data, how you're loading it, etc. Can you provide more information (ideally, an MCVE and a toy dataset)?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually limit the length of a run using the **Stop condition** in your BehaviorSpace experiment. You'll need a global to track the number of ticks to run, and then you'll need to populate it in the setup portion of your model:

```
globals [ ticks-to-run ]

to setup
  reset-ticks
  set ticks-to-run random 150 ; replace `random 150` by the data you load from your external source
end

to go 
  tick
end
```

This assumes you're running `setup` in your **Setup commands** and `go` in your **Go commands**.  Then in your **Stop condition** add `ticks > ticks-to-run` and your model will stop once it has ticked past your `ticks-to-run`.  Also make sure your **Time limit** is `0` in this case, as any value there would stop a model run before your custom `ticks-to-run` limit.